# Material UI Slider crashes while sliding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Material UI Slider won't slide and giving an error, but works fine if I'm not dragging a pointer and instead click the values manually.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null
at getFingerNewValue (Slider.js:617)
at Slider.js:682
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>"
```

I tried already everything that was advised on Stackoverflow and nothing helps.

I deleted some code: mostly other filters that I have in the code because it will be too long to post here.

```
// Filters "Parent Component"

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import icon from "./images/icon.png";
import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { useSpring, useChain, config, animated } from "react-spring";
import { Container } from "./styles";
import CustomSlider from "./CustomSlider";

export default function Filters({ data, PriceData, setMarkers }) {

const [value, setValue] = useState([0, 600000]);

const componentWillUnmount = useRef(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      componentWillUnmount.current = true;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (componentWillUnmount.current) {
        console.log(value);
      }
    };
  }, [value]); 

return (
    <>
 <Container
        style={{
          ...rest,
          width: size1,
          height: size2,
          top: transform,
          left: transform,
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="search-icon"
          onClick={() => setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen)}
          style={isOpen ? { visibility: "visible" } : { visibility: "visible" }}
        >
          <img src={icon} id="icon" alt="map search icon" />
        </div>
        <GlobalCss />
        <AnimatedForm
          style={{ ...rest2, display, opacity2, transform2 }}
          className="form"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <div className="ui grid">
           <div className="ui inverted divider"></div>

            <div className="sliderBox">
              <CustomSlider
                label="Select price range"
                value={value}
                setValue={setValue}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="ui inverted divider"></div>
          </div>
          <button id="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </AnimatedForm>
      </Container>
    </>
   </>
  );
}


// Slider "Child Component"

import React from "react";
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "none",
    width: 300 + 24 * 2,
    padding: 24,
  },
  margin: {
    height: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

const SliderItself = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "#a2df77",
    height: 8,
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "2px solid currentColor",
    marginTop: -8,
    marginLeft: -12,
    "&:focus,&:hover,&$active": {
      boxShadow: "inherit",
    },
  },
  active: {},
  valueLabel: {
    left: "calc(-50% + 4px)",
  },
  track: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  rail: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
})(Slider);

function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}`;
}

const CustomSlider = ({ label, value, setValue }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.margin} />
      <Typography gutterBottom>{label}</Typography>
      <SliderItself
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        value={value}
        min={0}
        step={10000}
        max={600000}
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        aria-labelledby="slider"
        onChange={(event, v) => {
          setValue(v);
        }}
      />
      Filter range is between {value[0]} and {value[1]}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CustomSlider;
```

Comment: Hi, Alba, Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Alba, any solution? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Oh just fixed it seconds after i wrote this. In my case, i had a `key` prop in my `Slider`. Removed it and it works